# Where can I find AniMove in QGIS 3.4?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I have found that to carry out a kernel density estimate others are using the plugin AniMove. Please could someone point me in the right direction I have looked in the Processing options and AniMove is not there under the provider's section?

Comment: plugins are available through the plugin menu > manage/install plugins, not the processing toolbox.

Comment: Thanks - I have tried that and clicked the box to show experimental plugins but it still isn't showing

Comment: This plug is heavily reliant on the adehabitat R package(s) so, as such is not available at QGIS version 3. Please take a look at the development page for animove at: https://www.faunalia.eu/en/dev/animove#animove-for-qgis

Comment: Sometimes plugins are discontinued when QGIS introduces a core function that makes the plugin unnecessary or redundant. Have you checked the tools in the processing toolbox?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

### For QGIS 3

The "Animove" plugin has been updated to QGIS 3, as can be seen on the plugin page: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/sextante_animove/

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### For QGIS 2

If you can install QGIS 2, it might be possible to install the plugin.

[image]